# iframe contents change event?

Tags: jquery, iframe

How can I detect when the iframe content has changed and do something upon that change pseudo code below

```
 $('#waframe').contents().change(function(){
   //do stuff
  });
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Well, the browser seems to generate a "load" event on an `<iframe>` element in the context of the containing page. The "load" fires when the "src" is changed; not sure whether it fires when the iframe changes itself.

**edit:** yes it does seem to fire when the page reloads "internally"

Thus you might try:

```
$('iframe#yourId').load(function() {
  alert("the iframe has been loaded");
});
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to fire in safari or opera I haven't checked ie or chrome yet

Comment: Hmm.  Well the Microsoft documentation is not clear on the topic. To test it out, all I did was have a little page with an iframe, and I pointed the iframe to a random domain of mine. In the test page, I just set up a jQuery event listener for "load" on the iframe element.

Comment: it does work in ff and thats cool but i'm gonna need something that works all the way around the board or a least most of the way

Comment: I have tested in Chrome 24.0.1312.XX, Opera 12.14, and Epiphany(GNOME browser), and Mozilla 18.0.2. It works on all these browsers. My OS is Linux 12.04 Ubuntu. Thanks @Pointy.

Answer (score 4):

Am doing a litle trick (dirt but it works) :) to display a loading object

```
function changeDet(old){ //detect src changes
    if($("iframe#ifID").attr('src') != old){
        $("iframe#ifID").width(0); //error if i hide ...?
    }

    setTimeout('changeDet("' + $("#db").attr('src') + '")',10);
}

var df = $('#iframe#ifID');

df.load(function(){ //content loaded
setTimeout('$("#db").width(var_default_width);',100);
});

changeDet();

$(function(){   
    //jq stuffs...
})
</script>
```

Comment: Not very viable because you have to do string comparisons for every 10 milliseconds, which can be easily a burden when doc size increases to MBs.

Comment: Avoid using string in `setTimeout` it is a) a security risk, b) slow, c) impossible for the JS interpreter to handle with any sanity.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to fire event on change.. Works on IE8 and firefox

```
if(document.addEventListener){
    yourIFrameObject.contentWindow.document.addEventListener('keyup', yourFunction, false);
   // window.frames[0].document.addEventListener('keyup', yourFunction, false);
}
else{
//for IE8
    yourIFrameObject.contentWindow.document.attachEvent('onkeyup', yourFunction);
}
```

You could use a `mouseup` statement if necessary

Answer (score 0):

In case when the HTML of an iframe is dynamic and you need to track it then this worked for me:

```
$('#waframe').contents().find('body').on('DOMSubtreeModified', function(){
    //do stuff
});
```