# Detect change events in Wordpress Edit Post page's Rich Text Editor(tinyMCE)

Tags: jquery, wordpress, iframe, tinymce

How I can detect that there was a change in the rich text editor in the Edit Post page?

What I want is to execute a function when the user typed something in the rich text editor (HTML and Visual panes).

**EDIT:** I accomplished that in the HTML pane associating a jQuery keyup event in the hidden textarea that tinyMCE create, but still I've not been able to detect user input in the Visual tab.

I'm using Wordpress 3.2.1 and I know that they are using tinyMCE for the rich text editor functionality.

Seems that **tinyMCE** uses an `iframe` to build the **Visual** tab in the rich text editor, so I tried the examples pointed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433966/iframe-contents-change-event) without any results.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you solved this? Now I'm looking for the same function. Thanks!

Comment: @HarkályGergő Thanks for your prompt :) I forgot adding my own take to this. I added what it worked for me, hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I was able to solve this issue by adding this code snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function ($) {
        // Was needed a timeout since RTE is not initialized when this code run.
        setTimeout(function () {
            for (var i = 0; i < tinymce.editors.length; i++) {
                tinymce.editors[i].onChange.add(function (ed, e) {
                    // Update HTML view textarea (that is the one used to send the data to server).
                    ed.save();
                });
            }
        }, 1000);
    });
</script>
```

Thannks to @HarkályGergő for his prompting to solve this question :)

Comment: Using `tinymce.editors[i].on('NodeChange keyup', function(...))` hooks to all events. I had problems with `change` only in TinyMCE 4.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure how to add this to WordPress, but from a TinyMCE perspective the [isDirty()](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3amethod.tinymce.Editor.isDirty) method on the editor should help.

So you could simply use

```
if (tinyMCE.activeEditor.isDirty()) {
  //Do something
}
```

to check the currently active editor. WordPress may give you alternative ways to access the editor instance.

Comment: Thanks for the help. That triggers an error in my jquery code telling that `tinyMCE.activeEditor` is `null`. Now I just need to figure out how fire the code from you when the editor contents change ;).

Comment: Works perfect, tested on WordPress 4.0 and 4.6

Comment: Also note that when WordPress autosaves, the editor is no longer "dirty".

Comment: FWIW and I know this is years old, but `tinyMCE.activeEditor` will only be set (non-null) when the user is in the Visual edit mode.

Comment: Be careful, current code only check active (first?) editor, and you may have multiple instances