# detecting new content in an iFrame

Tags: iframe

So I have an iFrame on my page. It is not loaded dynamically. It is part of the html.
I am uploading images and displaying them in the iFrame.

Is there a way to detect when the content of an iFrame has changed.
I want to call a function() once the iFrame get new content.

I've searched around, and the answers seem to deal with loading a new iFrame or changing the 'src'. I don't want to do either of those things.

The iframe has no 'src', and must be part of the starting html.

I've tried 'onchange', 'onhaschange' etc...

Thanks guys.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using an `iframe` that doesn't point to another source, instead of a `div` or other container?

Comment: using a <form> to upload images without changing page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a event fired when the iframe loads new content, jQuery makes listening to it painless:

```
$('iframe#yourId').load(function() {
    yourFunction();
});
```

Source: [iframe contents change event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433966/iframe-contents-change-event)

Comment: its bad practice to put external javascript at the beginning of an HTML document. It causes delays in page visibility.

Comment: Yes, that is generally where we put them.

Comment: Actually, I've been using http://www.webpagetest.org/ to make many dramatic improvements in page load time.