# Set css of multiple divs with same id

Tags: javascript, html, reveal.js

I have a reveal presentation in an iframe. Each slide has a div with an audio player in in and the divs id is "narration".

I have a button outside the frame that is used to hide/show this div. The problem is that it only does this for the first slide and not the rest.

EDIT : This seems to hide the divs :

```
function checkAudio() {
        if (document.getElementById('cb1').checked) {
var y = document.getElementById('ppt').contentWindow.document.getElementsByClassName('narration');
var i;
for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
  y[i].style.display = 'none';
}
        } else {
var y = document.getElementById('ppt').contentWindow.document.getElementsByClassName('narration');
var i;
for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
  y[i].style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
 }
```

HTML in iframe (There is one for each slide) :

```
<div id="narration"><p align="middle">
    <audio controls="" preload="none">
        <source src="mp3/2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio></p>
</div>
```

JS (outside of iframe):

```
 function checkAudio() {
     if (document.getElementById('cb1').checked) {
         document.getElementById('ppt').contentWindow.document.getElementById('narration').style.display = 'none';
     } else {
         document.getElementById('ppt').contentWindow.document.getElementById('narration').style.display = 'block';
     }
 }
```

Comment: You really shouldn't have multiple the same IDs in your html, that's what [classes](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/) are for. Are you able to change the IDs to classes?

Comment: I am , would that make a difference?

Comment: Yes, you need to change your IDs to classes in order to fix your issue. Using multiple the same IDs is just asking for trouble, really.

Comment: After changing the IDs to classes and changing `getElementById()` to `getElementsByClassName()`, do you still have the same issue?

Comment: i get a js error ,  but i think that may be because there isnt that class in the css.

Comment: JS errors aren't caused by any css. Have you changed the correct `getElementById` to `getElementsByClassName`?

Comment: I have . the error is Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined

Comment: The return value of getElementsByClassName is an Array, you have to loop over this array, check if style exists and set the value you want.

Comment: Cool . I used a for loop and it now works .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changing your IDs to classes ([read here why](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/)), you need to update your javascript code to handle the multiple divs via a [foreach](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp) loop.

```
function checkAudio() {
    var narrationDivs = document.getElementById('ppt').contentWindow.document.getElementsByClassName('narration');
    var newDisplay = "block";

    if (document.getElementById('cb1').checked) {
        newDisplay = "none";
    }

    narrationDivs.forEach(function(div) {
        div.style.display = newDisplay;
    });
}
```

In order to have the code run again when your iframe changes, you need to update your iframe changing function:

```
function setURL(url){ 
    document.getElementById('ppt').src = url; 
    checkAudio(); // Just run the function again!
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72564/discussion-on-answer-by-dark-ashelin-set-css-of-multiple-divs-with-same-id).

Comment: @bluefeet Jess does not have enough rep to enter a chatroom.

Comment: Since I moved the comments, they should be able to chat.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show a specific element using a button, you should use a specific ID. If you want to show all items using a single button you should use classes. You could also use classes to show a specific element e.g.: The 5th button will show the 5th element but this is not a good style.

Answer (score 1):

When the site in the iframe loads the next frame, your code doesn't know to hide the div it presents again. You need an event to process on.

You need to poll the id so that if it shows up again, you can hide it. See: [iframe contents change event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433966/iframe-contents-change-event)

Answer (score 0):

```
 function checkAudio() {
        if (document.getElementById('cb1').checked) {
var y = document.getElementById('ppt').contentWindow.document.getElementsByClassName('narration');
var i;
for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
  y[i].style.display = 'none';
}
        } else {
var y = document.getElementById('ppt').contentWindow.document.getElementsByClassName('narration');
var i;
for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
  y[i].style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to check out the `audio-slideshow` plugin that allows to play separate audio files for each slide and fragment. If your main need is this, the plugin should do the job for you.

You can find a demo [here](http://courses.telematique.eu/audio-slideshow/)  and the plugin [here](https://github.com/rajgoel/reveal.js/tree/audio-slideshow/plugin/audio-slideshow). There is also the `slideshow-recorder` plugin that allows you to record your narration.

Asvin