# Change height of iFrame when content changes

Tags: javascript, iframe

I've been trying to figure out how to change the size of my iFrame when the content changes within the iFrame. I've figured out how to get the iFrame to adjust to the correct height when the page loads. But I am still unable to figure out how to change the height of the iFrame when the content within changes.

Here is my code.

```
    <iframe src="http://www.silverbowpmdev.com/rlcodetest2/" style="top:0px;   left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:auto; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow-x:hidden;" scrolling="no" onload="javascript:resizeIframe(this);"></iframe>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function resizeIframe(obj) {
    obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
    }
    </script>
```

links to site: http://www.silverbowpmdev.com/rental-listings-test-2/

Comment: `onload` does not trigger in all browsers when the content changes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433966/iframe-contents-change-event

Comment: Is this a change in the src of the iframe or just the content?

Comment: just the content displayed. The iFrame houses code for a third party widget. There are different views the user can look at. When selecting a different view the content shrinks significantly leaving excessive white space below, and images that are supposed to be centered on the page become unviewable unless one scrolls down quite a ways.\